# In a pytorch tensor, return an array of indices of the rows of specific value

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

Given the below tensor that has vectors of all zeros and vectors with ones and zeros:

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0.],
    [1., 0., 0., 1.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],...])
```

How can I have an array of indices of the vectors with ones and zeros so the output is  like this:

```
indices = tensor([ 1, 3, 5, 6,...])
```

**Update**

A way to do it is:

```
indices = torch.unique(torch.nonzero(y>0,as_tuple=True)[0])
```

But I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way is to use [`torch.Tensor.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.any.html) coupled with [`torch.Tensor.nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nonzero.html):

```
>>> x.any(1).nonzero()[:,0]
tensor([1, 3, 5, 6])
```

Otherwise, since the tensor contains only positive value, you can sum the columns and mask:

```
>>> x.sum(1).nonzero()[:,0]
tensor([1, 3, 5, 6])
```